# Show last 12 months data from the selected date in my previous page

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a data which gives the over view of the product returns for each month for 4 years.

In powerbi sheet_1 i gave the overview of the products returns by month_year as a slicer.

And in another sheet i gave the overview of the products returns for all years with products as filter.
I wanted to filter the data in sheet_2 to show tha data for last 12 months from the selected month_year in my sheet_1.

I tried many ways but iam not able to get the desired output. Kindly help!!

I tried to store the selected date from sheet_1 and create a measure which filtes the data from that selected date. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

1. On your sheet_1, make sure your slicer is synced to sheet_2
   [image: Where to find the Sync slicers options]

---

2. Then check the check-box for syncing to page 2
   [image: ![enter image description here]

---

3. On your sheet_2, use this measure to se the sum of the last 12 months:

> ```
> Amount R12M = 
>  var _LastDate = LASTDATE(dimCalendar[Date])
>  var _calc =
>     CALCULATE(
>         [Amount],  ---<--- Your base measure
>         DATESINPERIOD(dimCalendar[Date],_LastDate,-12,MONTH)
>     )
> return _calc
> ```

Hope this helps!

---

Comment: Hi Thomasi, Thank you for ur time. I tried the method you mentioned above but when i select a month_year in page1 i only get the selected month data in next sheet not last 12 months.

Comment: Hi, I changed the picture in step 2 - it missed a mark. This works in my sample. 
Also - I'm using a date table, with a relationship to the sales table.